# codeigniter url link is not clickable

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a field in a db called 'website' when i output the database content in a view with

```
site: <?php echo $profile['site']; ?> <br/>
```

i get echo

```
http://facebook.com
```

but cannot click the link, I have also disabled xss filtering globally in config file. in my validation i have used only this

```
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('site', 'Website', 'min_length[5]|max_length[160]');
```

please help

Comment: I'm surprised you went that far without understanding basic html

Comment: my bad, too much into CI to forget basic html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A link only becomes clickable if it's formatted as one. You will need to put the appropriate html around it to make that happen.

```
site: <a href="<?php echo $profile['site']; ?>">It's a link!</a>
```

Comment: I'm gonna +1 grapefrukt for the _html way_

Answer (score 0):

in CodeIgniter way (using [URL helper](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html)) it will looks like:

```
echo anchor($profile['site'], 'Profile');
```

Answer (score 0):

use the URL helper and use the anchor() function to turn the variable into a link.

in the controller:

```
$this->load->helper('URL');
```

in the view:

```
<?php echo anchor($profile['site']); ?> <br/>
```